# Refresh WebView every 5 seconds

Tags: android-studio, webview, refresh, reload

I want to reload the WebView every some seconds using timer or delay method
or even delay within a loop

this is my code

```
  private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Timer repeatTask = new Timer();
repeatTask.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

   @Override
   public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
               webview.loadUrl("yoururl");  
         }
  });
  }
 }, 0, 5000);
```